# Characteristic polynomial of iterates

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an $n\times n$ integer matrix $A$ with $\det(A)=\pm1$, we can define the characteristic polynomial of $A$ as
$$\Delta(t)=\det(A-tI)$$
where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

So my question is:

> Does there exist a nice formula for $\Delta_n(t)=\det(A^n-tI)$ in terms of $\Delta(t)$?

Answer (score 2):

Not really a direct formula.  $\Delta(t) = \prod_j (\lambda_j - t)$ where $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, i.e. the roots of $\Delta$ (listed by algebraic multiplicity), and then $\Delta_n(t) = \prod_{j} (\lambda_j^n - t)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to show by induction that for $n \in N, \space x^n-y^n$ is divisible by $x-y$, then for A square of order $k$ ,  $(A^n-t^nI) \space$  has as a factor $(A-tI)$.  Then,

$det(A-tI)=0 \Rightarrow det(A^n-t^nI)=0$

Therefore:

$$\text{t is an eigenvalue of A} \Rightarrow t^n \text{ is an eigenvalue of } A^n$$

This means:

$$\Delta(t)=\prod_{i=1}^k (t-t_i)  \Rightarrow \Delta_n(t)=\prod_{i=1}^k (t-{t_i}^n)$$

Note: I changed the order of the matrix from n to k, because it is confusing to use the same name for the power of the  matrix and the order.